# Bootstrap is overriding my submit button on the form on my website

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress

[Rocksaw.com's Contact page](http://www.rocksaws.com/contact/)

Alright, so I am having a pretty tough time with my contact form working.
I am using bootstrap framework to lay everything out and each column is playing nicely until I view the site on a mobile device; a device with a screen size of 650px and below.

At 650px, my far right column breaks into my "submit" button on the contact form, rendering it inactive.

I am at a loss of where to look or what to do.

Here is the HTML of the page:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 home-product">

  <div class="container a1-container">

<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 feature-top">
  
<h1 class="home-heading">Contact Us Today!</h1>

</div>
  <div class="row">
  
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="product-text">

USA <a href="tel:+7202237888"><img src="http://www.rocksaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Screen-Shot-2015-04-13-at-1.10.33-PM.png" width=100px height=50px> </a>
<strong>info@rocksaws.com</strong>
<strong>6295 W. Crestline Ave.</strong>
<strong>Denver, Colorado 80123</strong>
<strong>USA</strong>

Rock Tools, LLC. is strategically located in Denver, Colorado to service the North American market and in Brighton, Sussex, UK to service the UK and Europe. With representatives in Germany, Turkey, Italy, Greece, Jordan, and Peru. We can meet your rock and concrete cutting requirements anywhere in the world.

<iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3073.417964747176!2d-105.06676300000001!3d39.617792!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x876b7fbab7f275ab%3A0xdf6bc7be355813d8!2sRock+Tools%2C+LLC!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1422991724107" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>

       </div>
</div>

<!--start of form-->


<div class="col-md-4">


[CONTACT_FORM_TO_EMAIL id="1"]
 
</div>
<!--end of form-->



     <div class= "col-md-4">
         
<strong>AGF Equipamentos- Brazil </strong>
642 Betel - Paulinia - SP CEP: 13148-160
Url : <a href="http://agfequipamentos.com.br/site/" target="_blank">http://agfequipamentos.com.br/site/</a>
Email: vendas@AGFEquipamentos.com.br
Phone: +55 19 3888-5800

<strong>Creighton Rock Drill Ltd.- Canada
</strong>2222 Drew Road
Mississauga ON L5S 1B1, Canada
Url: <a href="http://www.creightonrock.com">www.creightonrock.com</a>
Phone: 1 (905) 673-8200
Fax: 1 (905) 673-8208 / 1 (800) 667-4280

<strong>Proxy Trade-Germany</strong>
Toruń
ul. Wapienną 6/8
+48 600 913 600
tel. 056 66 01 913
fax. 056 66 23 913

<strong>Italy</strong>
Mirella Sartori
Phone: +39 339 607 5402

<strong> Verkfaeri ehf- Iceland</strong>
Gunnar Ólafsson
Sales Manager
gunnar@verkfaeriehf.is
Akralind 3 . 2 hæð
201 Kópavogur
Iceland
+354-859-9399 mobil
+354-544-4210 office
+354-544-4211 fax
www.verkfaeriehf.is
www.heavyequipment.is
www.lightequipment.is

<strong>Vektra-Turkey</strong>
Haluk Devran
Oz Ankara Sanayi Sitesi
1420 Cadde (Eski 28 Cadde)
1416 Sokak (Eski 632 Sokak)
No: 19 Yenimahalle 06378
Ankara
Url: http://<a href="http://www.vektra.com.tr" target="_blank">www.vektra.com.tr</a>
Email: <a href="mailto:vektra@vektra.com.tr">vektra@vektra.com.tr</a>
Phone: +90 532 613 9464

<strong>National Attachments LLC.- USA</strong>
Scotty Guimond
Gabe Guimond
80 Dow Rd. Gorham, ME 04038
Url : <a href="http://www.nationalattachments.com" target="_blank">www.nationalattachments.com</a>
Toll Free: (800) 839-9981
Phone: (207) 839-9999

<strong>United Kingdom</strong>
Url: <a href="http://www.rocksaw.co.uk">http://www.rocksaw.co.uk</a>
Phone: +44 1273 311 492
        
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS of the page:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

 #header {
  height: auto;
 }

 #searchform {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
 }

 #main-nav {
  position: static;
 }

 #site-logo {
  margin: 15px 100px 5px 0;
  position: static;
 }

 #site-description {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  position: static;
 }

 #content {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
 }

        


 #sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
 }

       

}
```

Comment: If any one is available for a google hangout, please please let me know. I understand we are supposed to put all content and answers here for others but I am a visual learner, talking it out helps me much more than typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not using `col-xs-` for small devices. For example:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product-text">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

should sort your problem.

Comment: Thank you! totally solved everything, you are a life saver. I was just to tired last night to trouble shoot such a simple addition. Thank you again!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

This quick and dirty fix will work.

```
.pbSubmit {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

It will essentially make sure that the button stays in front of the other elements on the page. (By default, elements inherit the property `z-index: 0;`

You can put it inside your media query, although you don't necessarily have to.

Comment: even if the form is a plugin? sorry I forgot to include that!